# React-hook-form input fields match validation best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

What's the best practice when doing input fields match validation when dealing with React-hook-form? For example, when matching `email` inputs, etc.

While looking into email match validation with React-hook-form found an issue while trying to separate error messages from "coupled elements" through their validation method. The `ref` only takes one argument that is used for React-hook-form `register`, while needing to use `useRef` to access the `current.value` for value matching, as follows:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const inputEmail = useRef(null)
  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log('onSubmit: ', JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        ref={inputEmail}
      />
      {/* desired: show `email` error message */}
      <label htmlFor="email">Email confirmation</label>
      <input
        name="emailConfirmation"
        type="email"
        ref={register({
          validate: {
            emailEqual: value => (value === inputEmail.current.value) || 'Email confirmation error!',
          }
        })}
      />
      {errors.emailConfirmation && <p>{errors.emailConfirmation.message}</p>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

While this pattern seems to be an option when doing input field matching it does not play well with React-hook-form!

For example, the error message is coupled with one input case only and has no separate messages for each independent field, or one of the input fields does not have the register assigned to it, this means that the property `required` is not set, etc.

So, I'm looking into a good practice or pattern that solves:

- Keeping error messages separated by the input field
- The validation method, when testing the match should be able to reference the twin field value in a React compliant way and not
  through the DOM (document.querySelector, etc)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't need the manual ref for `inputEmail`. Instead, use the [`getValues`](https://react-hook-form.com/api#getValues) method to fetch the current value of your whole form.

```
const { register, getValues } = useForm()
```

Then you register both inputs and call `getValues` from your custom validation.

```
  <input
    name="email"
    type="email"
    ref={register}
  />
  <input
    name="emailConfirmation"
    type="email"
    ref={register({
      validate: {
        emailEqual: value => (value === getValues().email) || 'Email confirmation error!',
      }
    })}
  />
```

Comment: That's a great answer Alex! I missed the `getValues`, wasn't aware of it, as I'm just starting out with react-hook-forms, happily learning ;) I'm sure this question will be useful to other people in the future! Thank you!

Comment: Getting vague errors when trying to use this in React Native (`t.split is not a function. (In 't.split[/[,[\].]+?/)', 't.split' is undefined)` [in `index.cjs.js`]). I think it's because I'm not initializing `ref` properly somehow... I have `import React, {useEffect, useState, Fragment, ref} from 'react';` at the top of my `.js`, and `const { control, handleSubmit, register, getValues, formState: { errors } } = useForm();` within the primary/exported function. Could someone please provide a full working React Native example in a sandbox?

Comment: Ignore my last comment...I just had to add `validate: {}` to my `rules={}` like this (e.g.,): `rules={{ required: { value: true, message: "This field is required." }, { validate: { emailEqual: value => (value === getValues().email) || "Emails don't match." } }}`. The `ref` and `register` mumbo jumbo is for React implementations and not React-Native, methinks...

Comment: Consider using validate function, which has formValues param, making getValues not necessary:

```const yourRules = {
  yourField: {
    validate: (value, formValues) => (value === formValues.otherField) || 'Error message'
  }
}```

Answer (score 2):

For this you could use `Yup` library, which is great:

Add `validationSchema` to your config object when instantiating `useForm` and pass a valid `Yup` schema. Like so:

```
const Schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().required('Required field'),
  emailConfirmation: yup
    .string()
    .oneOf([yup.ref('email')], 'Emails must match')
    .required('Required field'),
});

// How to add it to your useForm
const { register } = useForm({
  validationSchema: Schema
})
```

Your component should look something like this:

```
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    validationSchema: Schema
  });

  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log('onSubmit: ', JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        name="email"
        type="email"
        ref={register}
      />
      {/* desired: show `email` error message */}
      <label htmlFor="email">Email confirmation</label>
      <input
        name="emailConfirmation"
        type="email"
        ref={register}
      />
      {errors.emailConfirmation && <p>{errors.emailConfirmation.message}</p>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to validate a specific field before submit?